# Change SOAP request format

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I'm busy putting together a SOAP script which for the most part is working properly, however there is one request which wasn't working properly and have been asked to change the format of the request XML by the host company and I'm stuck...

Currently my XML request looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.???.com/???/">
  <env:Body>
    <ns1:GetTransactions>
      <ns1:Filter>
        <ns1:CardId>1234</ns1:CardId>
      </ns1:Filter>
      <ns1:Range>
        <ns1:FirstRow/>
        <ns1:LastRow/>
      </ns1:Range>
    </ns1:GetTransactions>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But the host company has requested that it looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Body>
    <GetTransactions xmlns="http://www.???.com/???/">
      <Filter>
        <CardId>1234</CardId>
      </Filter>
      <Range>
        <FirstRow/>
        <LastRow/>
      </Range>
    </GetTransactions>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

My PHP that forms the request is as follow...

```
$wsdl = 'http://???.com/???/???.asmx?WSDL';
$endpoint = 'http://???.com/???/???.asp';

$soap_client = new SoapClient( $wsdl, array(
    'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace'         => 1,
    'exceptions'    => 0,
    'features'      => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
    'location'      => $endpoint
) );

$get_transactions = $soap_client->GetTransactions( array(
    'Filter' => array(
        'CardId'    => '1234'
    ),
    'Range' => array(
        'FirstRow'  => NULL,
        'LastRow'   => NULL
    )
) );
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction with regard to what's required to change the format of the output XML?

Comment: Those are functionally equivalent. If that company request you change that they are inept, and if they have a correct soap service it would not make a difference. That being the case, before jumping through hoops: have you tried you original request, and just manually sending the request they seem to like (just post that string), and compared the return values of those? It would be a waste to put the effort in if it doesn't work.

Comment: That rant being said: it would most likely involve extending the `SoapClient` in a new class & overriding [`__doRequest()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php) with some custom alterations on the XML.

Comment: ... and coming back, [this works for altering the XML](http://codepad.org/tVQO4X04). I refuse to post it as an answer though: the real answer is they should accept _both_ formats.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, I understand your frustration. I've been searching for  a real solution for hours and you've confirmed my conclusion. I'm just working my way through your suggestions to see what I can come up with.

Comment: Yeah, working with broken 3rd parties is a pain. I'd go for a simple test first: `extend SoapClient`, override `__doRequest()` where you just replace the XML with the exact XML they say you have to use, and see if that works. If it does: their solution is broken, but you can work around it. If it doesn't: then you've proven with the minimal amount of effort the difference in XML is not the issue, and their error should be elsewhere, saving you the trouble of having to code a dynamical solution.

Comment: Testing confirms that it will work if done their way. I hate hacking stuff about but it looks like I'm going to have to do it. Thank you for your help and for proving I'm not crazy!

Comment: My hacked up solution was to extend the SoapClient class as you suggested. I'll post it as an addition to my original question, but as you say, I think the correct answer is for the host company to fix their web service!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with the host company's web service. The web service should accept the format being sent as it is properly formatted XML.

### A Hacky Solution

With thanks to Wrikken for his suggestions, I've come up with a hacky solution. The real answer would be for the host company to fix their web service to accept properly formatted XML requests.

I extended the SoapClient class so I could edit the XML before it's sent to the server...

```
$namespace = 'http://www.???.com/???/';

class HackySoapClient extends SoapClient {

    function __doRequest( $request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0 ) {

        global $namespace;

        // Here we remove the ns1: prefix and remove the xmlns attribute from the XML envelope.
        $request = str_replace( '<ns1:', '<', $request );
        $request = str_replace( '</ns1:', '</', $request );
        $request = str_replace( ' xmlns:ns1="' . $namespace . '"', '', $request );

        // The xmlns attribute must then be added to EVERY function called by this script.
        $request = str_replace( '<Login',           '<Login xmlns="' . $namespace . '"', $request );
        $request = str_replace( '<GetTransactions', '<GetTransactions xmlns="' . $namespace . '"', $request );

        return parent::__doRequest( $request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0 );

    }

}

$soap_client = new HackySoapClient( $wsdl, array(...
```

Comment: You are right it's hacky, but it works! I had the same problem with MS Navision complaining about ns1 namespace.

Comment: This just saved my life. So hacky, but if you're working with a terribly written soap API, I don't even feel bad about it.