# PHP SoapClient - action in the wrong place

Tags: php, soap

I'm using PHP SoapClient, and am running into an issue with getting the request format just as a third party wants it.

They want it like this:

```
POST /service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: service.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Order xmlns="http://someservice">
      <json>string</json>
    </Order>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

However, the closest I can seem to get it, using SoapClient, is like this:

```
POST /service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: service.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://someservice"
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Order>
      <json>string</json>
    </Order>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Notice how the action in my request is in the http header, and the action in their ideal format is in the Order tag. The thing is, it's SoapClient that is generating where that action is being placed - it gets that specific url from the WSDL, it's not even in my code.

How do I tell SoapClient to put it in the right spot? For my part, trying to only include what's necessary, this is essentially the code:

```
$this->client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, array(
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'stream_context' => stream_context_create($context),
                'trace' => true,
                'exceptions' => true,
            )
        );
    $json = json_encode($request);

    // Prepare the xml
    $xml = array();
    $xml[] = new SoapVar($json, XSD_STRING, 'string', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'json');

    $this->finalXML = new SoapVar($xml, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'Order');
    $this->response = $this->client->CreateOrder($this->finalXML);
```

Comment: What is `$context`? What is `$request`? How does this relate to the XML you show above? I don't see `http://someservice` anywhere in your code.

Comment: $context relates to one of my headers and isn't important for the question. $request relates to the json and only affects that, nothing to do with the XML. The url I'm referring to is generated from their WSDL, not my code.

Comment: Ok, just trying to figure out how the sample code relates to the sample XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change SOAP request format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21032594/1255289)

Comment: @miken32 nice, trolling a 5 month old question, where I referenced that exact link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of banging my head, I found this and ended up making the accepted, hacky solution work for me:

[Change SOAP request format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032594/change-soap-request-format)

Apparently, when you're working with a poorly written Soap API, there's not a lot you can do.